# Can the F-test be used when comparing 2 groups? Why not use the t-test?

Tags: t-test, f-test

I recently read a paper and the authors run a survey experiment that had 4 groups, including a control group. The author writes the following: "The treatment about better responding to economic crises has no systematic effect on exchange rate policy preferences. In addition, the estimated effect from T1 is larger than T2 (F-test βT1 > βT2, p-value = .06)."

What I don't understand is, why would the authors use an F-test instead of a one-tailed t-test? Is the result going to be the same? If not, what are some advantages on doing this? Lastly, when they say F-test, does that mean ANOVA?

Answer (score 3):

1. The "F-test" and the "ANOVA *test*" can be considered synonyms.  There are also the ANOVA *model* and the ANOVA *table*, e.g.
2. You can conduct an F-test on just 2 groups.  The F-statistic will be the square of the two-sided t-statistic.  The p-values from the two methods should be identical, although it's possible that there will be rounding differences at enough decimal places down due to different computational algorithms that the software uses.
3. The F-test does not allow for a directional test in the sense that a one-tailed t-test does.  So if there are only 2 groups and a directional test is desired, a t-test would make more sense.
4. I find the author's quoted phrasing a little awkward, but they seem to be saying that there is no effect, since p=.06 (i.e., >.05).  If so, that is a (common) fallacy.  You cannot conclude there is no effect just because the result is significant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Per the last answer, before even discussing about the p-value, since you said the F-test does not allow for a directional test, then you can't really run "F-test βT1 > βT2" which the authors said they did in their paper right?..

Comment: @chunguc1004, if there's some way of doing that, I don't know what it is.  It might be just that they ran a regular test & also looked to see if βT1 > βT2, or something ad hoc like that.